# Accessing attributes of backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm building my first application with Backbone + Marionette JS + Rails and I ran into issue with accessing model attributes. I fetch model from the server with the following code:

```
getCrewMember: (id) ->
            member = new Entities.Crew
                id: id
            member.fetch()
            member
```

Here is the output of console.log member :

...

```
attributes: Object
  crew: Object
    crewProperty1: "value1"
    crewProperty2: "value2"
  id: "1"
```

...

The question is how to access `crew: Object` properties? (`crewProperty1`, `crewProperty2`) and get there values, because I can only access id property.

Comment: var modelCrew = model.get('crew'); modelCrew.crewProperty1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Backbone models provide get and set methods for accessing, creating and updating attributes.

Id is exposed so you don't have to use get.

In your example you should be able to access the properties like this:

```
model.get('crew').crewProperty1 // value1
```